# Github mirror repository using workflow from another repo

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

My problem is I have mirror repository on GitHub, that I can't commit into. I have to run some pipelines on this repo. In GitLab CI, it's possible to select CI/CD configuration file from another repo. I searched throught actions repo settings, but I couldn't find anything that would help me. Is that possible in GitHub Actions? Or I have to find some workaround?

Comment: Just to confirm: your question is actually *can I have a GitHub action for some repository refer to some other repository*, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's almost correct, Let's just say i got 100 repositories, that would have identical workflow. I don't want to duplicate that one workflow into all 100 repositories. Because If i want to change the workflow I have to do it 100 times. I looked at Github Roadmap and this feature is on the way in Q4 2021, so I think I have to wait for it.  In GitLab, you can just point out workflow definition from another repo.

Comment: OK, yes, it looks like one of those cases where GitLab is ahead of GitHub here. Note that base Git doesn't have any of this stuff...